# Django conditional annotation count with filter (many-to-many) follower/following table

Tags: python, django, annotations, conditional-statements

This is a bit of a mind bender for me so I decided to ask for some help.

What I have is a standard user model and a table which tracks if users follow each other which has a `from_user`, `to_user`, and `following` values. The first to being foreignkeys to my user table the third is a boolean value.

What I want to do is be able to override the default `get_queryset` method in django admin so I can sort based on the number of followers the users have.

Where I'm currently stuck is at actually annotating the number of followers, it might be something small I'm missing and derping out but here is my code:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    return AuthUser.objects.annotate(
        followers_count=Sum(
            Case(
                When(user_relations__from_user=1, user_relations__to_relation__following=True, then=1),
                default=0,
                output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        ))
```

The part that is wrong - I'm stuck at using the `user_relations__from_user=1` which should be the current user being evaluated's id.

What I need to do in the aggregation for all entries is something I'm already doing on a single case scenario inside the User model:

```
@property
def num_followers(self):
    return UserRelations.objects.filter(from_user=self, following=True).count()
```

It seems simple but how do I get the `from_user=self` when annotating?

EDIT: Adding stack trace when trying to use F `user_relations__from_user_id__pk=F('id')`

An additional note - my `from_user` and `to_user` fk fields are actually named `from_user_id` and `to_user_id` - hope this doesn't lead to additional confusion. Sorry about that.

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/pkm_user/authuser/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bastor/Work/pokemall-api/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/bastor/Work/pokemall-api/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 616, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bastor/Work/pokemall-api/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 110, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bastor/Work/pokemall-api/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bastor/Work/pokemall-api/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 233, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bastor/Work/pokemall-api/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 34, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bastor/Work/pokemall-api/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 110, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bastor/Work/pokemall-api/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 30, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/home/bastor/Work/pokemall-api/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1548, in changelist_view
    self.list_max_show_all, self.list_editable, self)
  File "/home/bastor/Work/pokemall-api/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.root_queryset = model_admin.get_queryset(request)
  File "/home/bastor/Work/pokemall-api/django/pkm_user/admin.py", line 65, in get_queryset
    output_field=IntegerField()
  File "/home/bastor/Work/pokemall-api/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 794, in annotate
    obj.query.add_annotation(annotation, alias, is_summary=False)
  File "/home/bastor/Work/pokemall-api/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 977, in add_annotation
    summarize=is_summary)
  File "/home/bastor/Work/pokemall-api/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/aggregates.py", line 20, in resolve_expression
    c = super(Aggregate, self).resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize)
  File "/home/bastor/Work/pokemall-api/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 491, in resolve_expression
    c.source_expressions[pos] = arg.resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize, for_save)
  File "/home/bastor/Work/pokemall-api/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 779, in resolve_expression
    c.cases[pos] = case.resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize, for_save)
  File "/home/bastor/Work/pokemall-api/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 713, in resolve_expression
    c.condition = c.condition.resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize, False)
  File "/home/bastor/Work/pokemall-api/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query_utils.py", line 91, in resolve_expression
    clause, joins = query._add_q(self, reuse, allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=False)
  File "/home/bastor/Work/pokemall-api/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1332, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/home/bastor/Work/pokemall-api/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1194, in build_filter
    lookups, value)
  File "/home/bastor/Work/pokemall-api/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1709, in get_lookup_constraint
    raise exceptions.FieldError('Relation fields do not support nested lookups')
FieldError: Relation fields do not support nested lookups
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`F` expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F):

```
from django.db.models import F

def get_queryset(self, request):
    return AuthUser.objects.annotate(
        followers_count=Sum(
            Case(
                When(user_relations__to_relation__from_user__id=F('id'),
                     user_relations__to_relation__following=True, then=1),
                default=0,
                output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        ))
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the quick reply and for the F information! It really rocks and is a good-to-know type of thing.
I seem to be getting an
```Relation fields do not support nested lookups```
error for some reason when using it as you described though.

Comment: Hmmm. Can you post as an edit to your question the stack trace for this error?

Comment: I've edited the answer based on your feedback about your model structure - hopefully that is correct.

Comment: Oh my how embarrassing.

I messed up the relation should have been user_relations__to_relation__from_user_id=F('id') Forgot the to_relation

It doesn't give any errors now but the annotation seems to be incorrect. Like the sort is wrong. I'll toy with F() a bit more though. Maybe I'm still missing something fairly obvious. Thanks a lot for the help! :)

Comment: It doesn't look like it is sorting at all currently? You should be able to add an order_by clause to sort the results. Assuming that is what you mean by sort.

Comment: The main reason I'm doing the annotation is to order the fields in django admin by the number of followers

So after the annotation I'm using the ```admin_order_field``` to sort the results there and they aren't really correct. I'll log the query that has been executed and start from there I guess.